# is there a way to export gridview data to Instagram-friendly picture?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, instagram

I have data in access databases, and these data varies day by day. I can export data to GridView easily.

I have an idea to broadcast the data into Instagram. So, is there a way to export the gridview into Instagram-Friendly photo?

any idea will be very valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DrawToBitmap method of the data grid view control to save it as an image and then post that image to Instagram.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub GridViewToImage(fileName As String)
        Dim grdBitmap As New Bitmap(DataGridView1.Width, DataGridView1.Height)
        DataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(grdBitmap, DataGridView1.ClientRectangle)
        grdBitmap.Save(fileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        GridViewToImage("<your path here>\test.jpg")
        MessageBox.Show("Done")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Hope this helps.